# Size of UIImage after UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to figure out what the size of a UIImage is after a picture is taken with `UIImagePickerController` and how to properly scale the image taken. If I wanted the camera to take a picture 100pt x 100pt every time, how would I accomplish this?

I consulted the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) for `UIImagePickerController` but it didn't have anything on image size

Comment: UIImage has a size property.

Comment: You can simply redraw the image after the photo was picked/taken into the `CGSize` you want.

Comment: @troop231 wouldn't that require distorting the image?

Comment: Not at all my friend. Also would be something like this: `CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(100.0, 100.0);`

Comment: Do some searching. There are plenty of existing discussions on scaling an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something like this is what you're after. Please let me know though if I'm wrong.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    CGFloat var1;
    CGFloat var2;

    if (image.size.width > image.size.height){
        // Landscape
        CGFloat aspect = image.size.width / image.size.height;
        CGFloat height = ceilf(100.0/aspect);
        var1 = 100.0;
        var2 = height;
    }
    else if (image.size.height > image.size.width){
        // Portrait
        CGFloat aspect = image.size.height / image.size.width;
        CGFloat width = ceilf(100.0/aspect);
        var1 = width;
        var2 = 100.0;
    }
    else{
        // Square
        var1 = 100.0;
        var2 = 100.0;
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(var1, var2), NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, var1, var2)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```